# Async Programming, hangs on IIS but runs ok in IIS Express

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, asp.net-core

I have this file that hangs, i have some idea that it is caused by the async task, but not sure how to fix it and debugging doesnt really work since it works correctly on visual studio but fails on IIS proper..

I tried to use `ConfigureAwait(false);` which i read somewhere should resolve the issue but to no avail,

I also tried other methods to set my response.redirect in my other pages and complete the request, but also to no avail..

```
 Response.Redirect("Project.aspx", false);
 Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Here is my code.. appreciate if someone can point me to the right direction?

```
    protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                try
                {
                    LoggingController.log("Before Init Project");
                   await InitProject().ConfigureAwait(false); ;

                    LoggingController.log("After Init Project");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LoggingController.log(ex);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"].Equals("RedirectBoard"))
                {
                    await Task.Run(() => gotoProject(Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"])).ConfigureAwait(false); ;
                }
            }
        }


protected async Task InitProject()
        {
            try
            {
                // Login - temporary for fast testing
                if (Session["user"] == null)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx", false);
                    Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
                }
                else
                {
                    user = (Model.UserModel)Session["user"];
                }

                // Init variables
                int userID = user.User_ID;
                int role = user.Role;
                lists = new StringBuilder("const userID=" + userID + ";");

                // Start tasks
                // var timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
                // Task[] task = new Task[2];
                Task task0 = Task.Run(() => loadProject(userID, role));
                Task task1 = Task.Run(() => loadUser(userID));

                // Profile area
                var profile = (Image)Master.FindControl("profile");
                profile.ToolTip = user.Name;
                profile.ImageUrl = user.Avatar;
                new LanbanAuthentication().Authenticate(Response, user);

                // Wait all tasks to be completed
                await Task.WhenAll(task0, task1).ConfigureAwait(false);
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "projectScript", lists.ToString(), true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LoggingController.log(ex.Message + " @ " + ex.Source + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }



        //1. Load all projects
        protected async Task loadProject(int userID, int role)
        {
            try
            {
                // Fetch all projects belong to or under supervised of this user
                ProjectAccess myAccess = new ProjectAccess();
                myAccess.fetchProject(userID, role);
                var project = myAccess.MyDataSet.Tables["Project"];

                Task task1 = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < project.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var row = project.Rows[i];
                        if (row != null)
                            projectbrowser.Controls.Add(ProjectBox(row));
                    }
                });

                // Send project list in JSON to client for further processing
                Task task2 = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    StringBuilder projectList = new StringBuilder("var projectList = ");
                    if (project != null)
                    {
                        projectList.Append(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(project));
                        projectList.Append(";");
                        lists.Append(projectList);
                    }
                });

                await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2).ConfigureAwait(false); ;
                myAccess.Dipose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LoggingController.log(ex.Message + " @ " + ex.Source + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
            }

            LoggingController.log("loadProject completed");
        }

 private void loadUser(int userID)
        {
            // Fetch data from database
            ProjectAccess myAccess = new ProjectAccess();
            myAccess.fetchSharedProjectUser(userID);
            var user = myAccess.MyDataSet.Tables["User"];

            // Send user list in JSON to client for further processing
            StringBuilder userList = new StringBuilder("var userList = ");
            userList.Append(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));
            userList.Append(";");
            lists.Append(userList);
            myAccess.Dipose();

            LoggingController.log("loadUser completed");
        }
```

One of my Async Handler

```
/// Async handler for request from client
public class ProjectHandler : IHttpAsyncHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
{
    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

    public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
    {
        ProjectHandlerOperation operation = new ProjectHandlerOperation(callback, context, state);
        operation.QueueWork();
        return operation;
    }

    public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {

    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, It hangs at the end of Page_Load, doesnt complete the request.. even tho  LoggingController.log("After Init Project"); has finish execution

Comment: Hi, I added my async handler to the initial post..

Comment: Are you sure the IIS app pool use the correct .net framework version?

Comment: Try to replace you `async void` with `async Task`

Comment: `async void` won't work with ASP.NET Core. Are you sure you're using ASP.NET **Core**?

Comment: Yes.. im sure.. sry i didnt know async void doesnt work in .Net core..